# Error code 1248, SQL state 42000: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am running this query on MySQL.

```
Select Vendor, sum(Rate) as Rate
from (select case Vendor when 'NSN' then 'Nokia' else Vendor end as Vendor, Rate
from (  Select vendor ,(count(1) )*100/(Select count(id_incident)from incident where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30') as Rate from incident  where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30'group by upper (vendor) )) as y group by vendor;
```

and it is giving this error:

> Error code 1248, SQL state 42000: Every derived table must have its own alias".

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give the inner subquery an alias. I chose `x`

```
Select Vendor, sum(Rate) as Rate
from 
(
   select case Vendor when 'NSN' then 'Nokia' else Vendor end as Vendor, Rate
   from 
   (  
     Select vendor ,(count(1) )*100/(Select count(id_incident)from incident where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30') as Rate 
     from incident  
     where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30'
     group by upper (vendor) 
   ) as x
) as y 
group by vendor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is way more complicated than it needs to be:

```
 Select (case when vendor = 'NSN' then 'NOKIA' else upper(vendor) end) as vendor,
        count(*)*100 / overall.cnt as Rate 
 from incident i cross join
      (Select count(*) as cnt
       from incident
       where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30'
      ) overall
 where open_time between '2015-01-01'and'2015-01-30'
 group by (case when vendor = 'NSN' then 'NOKIA' else upper(vendor) end)
```

Comments:

- Subqueries (in MySQL) incur extra overhead for materializing the intermediate results.
- A subquery in the `select` clause is called once for each row.  In the `from`, it is only calculated once.
- If `id_incident` is not NULL, then just use `count(*)` (or `count(1)`).  It is misleading to put a column in the `count()`, when you are not really checking for `NULL` values.